# How to obtain SHA1 certificate for Android studio 3.2.2?

Tags: android-studio

I have seen many videos on how to obtain SHA1 certificate for Android Studio but they were all for other versions. There is no option for generating 'signed APK' in my Android Studio. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to get SHA1 is through Android Studio.

1. Open gradle window from right side.
2. Right click on ProjectName-> Tasks-> android-> signingReport
3. Choose Run (1st option).

you will get SHA1 and MD5 inside your Run window at bottom which will be automatically opened after clicking on Run (Step 3).

Here is the Snapshot:-

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

**Getting your SHA1 key is a little more complicated on a Windows system so, follow along with my steps here:**

1) Open Command Prompt by pressing Start+R and typing cmd.exe.

2) Using Windows Explorer, find where your JDK directory is located (Usually Program Files >> Java) and copy the path.

3) In Command Prompt, type cd followed by the directory of your JDK’s bin directory. e.g: cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin is the command I use (Yours may vary).

4) Using Windows Explorer, find where your .android directory is located (Usually under Users >> [YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]) and copy the path.

5) Now, use this command below:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore [PATH_TO_.ANDROID_DIRECTORY] -list -v

Replacing [PATH_TO_.ANDROID_DIRECTORY] with the path you copied. Note that you should be running this command in terminal/command prompt in your JDK’s bin directory (You did this in Step 3).

You should then be prompted with the password as normal which you can enter (The password is android) . After that, you’ll see the list of certificates printed to the screen. You want the SHA1 key.

In Command Prompt, it’s a little more tricky to copy the result so, to do that, follow these instructions:

1) Right-click on the Command Prompt.

2) Select Mark.

3) Highlight the SHA1 key.

4) Right-click again and the text will then be copied to your clipboard. You can now enter this on the Google Developer’s Console.